# Topology - Metric Space

Tags: general-topology

Show that $d_3$ is a metric space for $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$d_3((x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2))=max.${$|x_1-x_2|,|y_1-y_2|$}$.$

To show something is a metric space d has to have the following properties:

(a) $d(x,y) \ge 0$ for all $x \in X$ and all $y \in X.$

(b) $d(x,y)=0$ iff x=y for all $x \in X$ and all $y \in X.$

(c) $d(x,y) = d(x,y)$ for all $x \in X$ and all $y \in X.$

(d) $d(x,y) \le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ for all $x \in X$, all $y \in X.$, and all $z \in X$.

Attempt:

(a)  Because of the absolute values $d(x,y)$ has to be greater than 0.

(b)  When x=y $x_1=y_1$ and $x_2=y_2$ which results in $d_3$ being = {0,0}

(c)  Because of the absolute values it doesn't matter which way you subtract the two numbers from one another they will still equal the same number and thus when you switch x and y it is equal to the original.

(d)  No, clue...

Answer (score 1):

For $(b)$ you have to show if and only if so you are not done. For (d) note that:

$|x_{1}-x_{3}|=|(x_{1}-x_{2})+(x_{2}-x_{3})|\le|x_{1}-x_{2}|+|x_{2}-x_{3}|$

$\le\max\{|x_{1}-x_{2},|y_{1}-y_{2}||\}+\max\{|x_{2}-x_{3}|,|y_{2}-y_{3}|\}$

$=d_{3}((x_{1},y_{1}),(x_{2},y_{2}))+d_{3}((x_{2},y_{2}),(x_{3},y_{3}))$

By proceeding similarly with $|y_{1}-y_{3}|$ you get the triangle inequality for the metric.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, a metric d on a space X is a function $d:X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. So for (b), if $x=y\to x_1=x_2$and$y_1=y_2\to|x_1-x_2|=0$ and $|y_1-y_2|=0\to max\{|x_1-x_2|,|y_1-y_2|\}=0$. For the opposite, if the maximum of some non netative values is zero then each value is zero thus x=y. For (d) just use the hint user71352 made.